# MySQL starts using > 90% of CPU, "Copying to tmp table on disk" and "converting HEAP to MyISAM"

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, drupal

I have a server where MySQL is periodically taking up 11 of the 12 CPU cores. Once this starts it doesn't end until I restart MySQL. At least, I haven't let it run like this for more than a half hour since it takes down a live website. I haven't been able to notice any patterns for when or why this happens. It's not at times of particularly high traffic and the queries being run are not abnormal to what is normally run.

Here's what I get from `PROCESS LIST;`

```
mysql> show processlist;
+---------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+-------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id      | User       | Host                 | db      | Command     | Time   | State                                                                 | Info                                                                                                 |
+---------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+-------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1001328 | replicator | example.linode:59815 | NULL    | Binlog Dump | 316247 | Master has sent all binlog to slave; waiting for binlog to be updated | NULL                                                                                                 |
| 2356160 | example    | example:33965        | example | Query       |    398 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2356492 | example    | example:34727        | example | Query       |    318 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2361305 | example    | example:46892        | example | Query       |    771 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
[... 198 more lines like the one above, "Copying to tmp table on disk" ...]
| 2362323 | example    | example:49232        | example | Query       |    695 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT COUNT(*) AS expression
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node |
| 2362328 | example    | example:49244        | example | Query       |    694 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
[... 164 more lines like the one above, "Copying to tmp table on disk" ...]
| 2362857 | example    | example:50507        | example | Query       |    428 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362858 | example    | example:50509        | example | Query       |    427 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362859 | example    | example:50511        | example | Query       |    428 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362860 | example    | example:50514        | example | Query       |    427 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362861 | example    | example:50516        | example | Query       |    427 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362862 | example    | example:50519        | example | Query       |    427 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362863 | example    | example:50522        | example | Query       |    427 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362864 | example    | example:50524        | example | Query       |    425 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362865 | example    | example:50526        | example | Query       |    425 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362866 | example    | example:50529        | example | Query       |    424 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362868 | example    | example:50533        | example | Query       |    423 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362871 | example    | example:50537        | example | Query       |    422 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362872 | example    | example:50539        | example | Query       |    422 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362873 | example    | example:50544        | example | Query       |    421 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362874 | example    | example:50546        | example | Query       |    421 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362875 | example    | example:50548        | example | Query       |    421 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362876 | example    | example:50552        | example | Query       |    419 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362877 | example    | example:50556        | example | Query       |    418 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362878 | example    | example:50559        | example | Query       |    417 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362880 | example    | example:50565        | example | Query       |    417 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362881 | example    | example:50567        | example | Query       |    416 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362882 | example    | example:50570        | example | Query       |    413 | Copying to tmp table on disk                                          | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
| 2362883 | example    | example:50572        | example | Query       |    412 | converting HEAP to MyISAM                                             | SELECT DISTINCT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS |
[... 67 more lines like the one above, "converting HEAP to MyISAM" ...]
| 2362976 | root       | localhost            | NULL            | Query       |      0 | NULL                                                                  | show processlist                                                                                     |
+---------+------------+----------------------+-----------------+-------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
452 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, it's about 375 lines of "Copying tmp table on disk" and about 75 of "converting HEAP to MyISAM". My first reaction is to follow the instructions in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532307/skip-copying-to-tmp-table-on-disk-mysql/7533095#7533095) from @RolandoMySQLDBA and either increase the variables tmp_table_size and/or max_heap_table_size (but how can I know the amount) or set them as small as possible and create a RAM disk for MySQL's temp directory. But I thought I'd ask before doing something I don't completely understand.

What can I do to further understand the problem? What are the likely issues causing this? Are either of those ideas (increase tmp_table_size, max_heap_table_size; or create RAM disk) applicable to this situation?

Some more details:

Server has 32GB of RAM of which I would be comfortable dedicating 10GB to a RAM disk. It's running Ubuntu `14.04.3` and MySQL `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.44, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3`. The MySQL server is being replicated to a slave at a different host.

The vast majority of the tables are InnoDB.

Customized MySQL variables:

```
[mysqld]
server-id         = <omitted>
bind-address      = <omitted>
log_bin           = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
query_cache_limit = 6M
query_cache_size  = 128M
innodb_file_per_table
default-storage-engine = InnoDB
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
sync_binlog                    = 1

relay_log_purge       = 1
relay_log_space_limit = 10G

max_connections         = 1024
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
  # Set based on recommendations from http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39504/34815
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
  # @see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-buffer-pools.html
```

Also:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%_table_size";
+---------------------+----------+
| Variable_name       | Value    |
+---------------------+----------+
| max_heap_table_size | 16777216 |
| tmp_table_size      | 16777216 |
+---------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is out of my area of expertise. Any help is appreciated.

**Update** 
Per the request of Raymond Nijland, the `SHOW CREATE TABLE main_node` output. `main_node` is the main table being queried above, though it was likely joined with several other tables. I foolishly forgot to to run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` before restarting MySQL. Note that there should be nothing special about this table, it is one of the most used tables of Drupal sites.

```
CREATE TABLE `main_node` (
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'The primary identifier for a node.',
  `vid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The current main_node_revision.vid version identifier.',
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The main_node_type.type of this node.',
  `language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The main_languages.language of this node.',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The title of this node, always treated as non-markup plain text.',
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The main_users.uid that owns this node; initially, this is the user that created it.',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Boolean indicating whether the node is published (visible to non-administrators).',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The Unix timestamp when the node was created.',
  `changed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The Unix timestamp when the node was most recently saved.',
  `comment` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Whether comments are allowed on this node: 0 = no, 1 = closed (read only), 2 = open (read/write).',
  `promote` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Boolean indicating whether the node should be displayed on the front page.',
  `sticky` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Boolean indicating whether the node should be displayed at the top of lists in which it appears.',
  `tnid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'The translation set id for this node, which equals the node id of the source post in each set.',
  `translate` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A boolean indicating whether this translation page needs to be updated.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`nid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `vid` (`vid`),
  KEY `node_changed` (`changed`),
  KEY `node_created` (`created`),
  KEY `node_frontpage` (`promote`,`status`,`sticky`,`created`),
  KEY `node_status_type` (`status`,`type`,`nid`),
  KEY `node_title_type` (`title`,`type`(4)),
  KEY `node_type` (`type`(4)),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `tnid` (`tnid`),
  KEY `translate` (`translate`),
  KEY `language` (`language`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=58237 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='The base table for nodes.';
```

Comment: Did you check htop or something similar? Is it possible that the server may be swapping at that moment? 16MB * 425 tmp tables = some 7GB of memory only for the temp tables and then moved to disk if the reason for those converts is the size limit. Consider optimizing those queries to not use so big tmp tables.

Comment: I checked the monit history and it showed RAM usage only go up to 60%. When the system is running normally, there is only about 20% usage (6.4 of 32GB). Unfortunately, since the system is Drupal and it can be difficult to optimize queries without coding around Drupal. Since this only happens occasionally, I'm guessing it may not be the fault of the queries but something else is stalling them.

Comment: You should also post the output off `show create table [table_name]`

Comment: @RaymondNijland Added the output to the question.

Comment: @donut well i dont see your complete query but it looks like your problem is caused by the DISTINCT and the 512 bytes limit read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland The `title` column is the largest string column but it's limited to a 255 characters (=bytes?) length. Would this still be the cause? If I was able to limit `DISTINCT` to the `nid` column (`DISTINCT(node.nid)`) would that allow the use of a temporary table?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Just realized my misunderstanding of how `DISTINCT` works. So, ignore my second question about using it on a single column.

Comment: That `SELECT` needs to be improved -- either by adding an index or by reformulating it.  Please show us the `SELECT` and the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Don't use "prefix indexes" (`type(4)`), they tend to be worse than not having the index.  Get rid of the "(4)" since the column is only 32.

Comment: The "reason" for taking up all the CPU, etc, is that you are doing this one query a lot, and the many copies are stumbling over each other.

Comment: "Converting HEAP to MyISAM" means that (1) a tmp table was needed; (2) the limitations of MEMORY (alias HEAP) were met, so it started to build the tmp table in RAM; but (3) it got too big, so it converted to MyISAM.  Let's work on optimizing the query!

Comment: Don't blindly increase `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` -- because whatever you set them to may be multiplied by (375+75) for RAM usage in this extreme situation.  Blowing out RAM will be even worse.

Comment: Two unique INTs (nid, vid) for the same table??  Suggest thinking about getting rid of one of them.

Comment: @RickJames Unfortunately, because this table is generated by the Drupal 7 PHP framework/CMS I can't really modify it. I was actually able to avoid this problem by removing `DISTINCT` from most of the queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this isn't quite the answer I was looking for, the problem seems to have been resolved. Raymond Nijland pointed out that I was likely hitting the 512 byte read limit for `DISTINCT`:

> @donut well i dont see your complete query but it looks like your problem is caused by the DISTINCT and the 512 bytes limit read this [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) – Raymond Nijland Sep 23 at 22:18

I reevaluated the queries I most suspected to be causing these problems and determined I was able to remove `DISTINCT` from most of them. Since removing it I have not encountered this issue again.

Comment: Note that `title` is `varchar(255) CHARSET utf8` which takes 767 bytes -- more than 512.  Decreasing `title` to about 190 might allow `DISTINCT` (but might be too short for the application).

Comment: Getting rid of the `DISTINCT` not only avoids switching from `MEMORY` to `MyISAM`, but it _may_ also avoid creating the tmp table.  (I say _may_ because I can't see the `SELECT` or its `EXPLAIN` to be sure.)